# Free C Language IDEs?

Tags: c, ide

Googling for "c ide -C++" produces too many results for C++, as well as unrelated results. These search terms seem too short to produce relevant results. Does anyone have a link to a free, Win32 C IDE that does step-through debugging like Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm looking for C, not C++ ... does it matter? Those links are for C++.

Comment: @lothar, I think you'd be better putting possible dupes as a comment rather than editing the question. In any case, that link you put was just for the best, this one is specifically for a free one, which is not the same (darned close, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many IDEs these days support very many languages, and most C++ IDEs have perfectly fine support for C.

I'd recommend [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), a Free, cross-platform IDE that supports many compilers.

Comment: I can't believe Code::Blocks isn't at the top of every one of these IDE topics. It really is the best one besides MS Visual Studio.

Comment: This looks sweet! Just what I think I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Adam, if it's the best other than MSVC and MSVC Express is free, then Code::Blocks should be second on al the lists, not "at the top" :-)

Comment: Interesting... this is the second time in as many days that I've heard Code::Blocks mentioned... maybe I should take a look at it.

Comment: i tried code:blocks and i can say it is awesome.

Answer (score 15):

Visual studio has an express edition that´s free.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/default.aspx

EDIT: VS does compile C and  C++

> Microsoft Visual C++ is Microsoft's
>   implementation of the C and C++
>   compiler and associated languages
>   services and specific tools for
>   integration with the Visual Studio
>   IDE. It can compile either in C mode
>   or C++ mode. For C, it follows the ISO
>   C standard with parts of C99 spec
>   along with MS-specific additions in
>   the form of libraries.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Included_products

Comment: +1. You can't get any more "step-through debugging like Visual Studio" than Visual Studio :-)

Comment: The quote doesn't seem to agree with your conclusion.  Last time I tried, VS compiled C as C.

Comment: I meant it compiles both C and C++. Thanks. I´ll rewrite.

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse has a [C Development Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).

Answer (score 5):

Although it seems like a lot of people don't realize it, [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) also has plugins for C++.

Comment: I am so surprised nobody mentioned NetBeans.  It is one of slickest environments and totally free for a download.

Answer (score 4):

[Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) is an open source IDE for c/c++

Here is the features list:

- Support GCC-based compilers
- Integrated debugging (using GDB)
- Project Manager
- Customizable syntax highlighting editor
- Class Browser
- Code Completion
- Function listing
- Profiling support
- Quickly create Windows, console, static libraries and DLLs
- Support of templates for creating your own project types
- Makefile creation
- Edit and compile Resource files
- Tool Manager
- Print support
- Find and replace facilities
- CVS support

Comment: Dev-Cpp's development has stalled and it is somewhat buggy.

Comment: Agreed... though unfortunately, I'm too lazy to switch away from it...

Comment: Me too, as it happens. But I guess I don't really code for Windows very often.

Answer (score 4):

[lcc32](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~lcc-win32/), [MingWin studio](http://en.kioskea.net/telecharger/telecharger-608-mingw-developer-studio)

Answer (score 3):

The "C++ IDE's" work with C codes as well.

Answer (score 2):

I should point out that MSVC has C compiler. If you name your file .c it will use the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Watcom C/C++](http://openwatcom.org/index.php/Main_Page) - not just the IDE but the entire set of compilers and tools for development

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse - although it's heavy and nasty and likes to crash it's probably the best solution among free IDEs.